# Repair or force delete corrupt tables

Tags: mysql

I have an database with the name "build", and when I try to execute "USE BUILD" the MySQL server just crashes, it also crashes when I try to show the tables with phpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench. I do know that some of the tables inside that database is corrupt, but not all of the tables are corrupt.

An external software is able to access most of the tables there without crashing the MySQL server, but if it tries to access one of the corrupted tables it crashes instantly.

Some say I should use "REPAIR TABLE corrupt_table", but to execute that command I need to access the database before executing it which is impossible in my case because it crashes the MySQL server.

I just want the corrupted tables away, they are bothering me. It does not matter if I lose the data which is inside the corrupted tables, but I cannot lose the whole database. Is there a way to repair or, perferably force delete them?

Comment: Is the table MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: What files are in the `BUILD` directory under mysql's data directory?